# How to vertically align chemical reaction equation with equation number

Tags: math-mode, chemfig

The following code using `chemfig` placed in an `equation` produces the equation number at a too low position. How can I get the equation number vertically aligned with the arrow?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\schemestart
\setcrambond{2pt}{}{}
\chemfig{HO-[2,0.5,2]?<[7,0.7](-[2,0.5]OH)-[0,,,,
line width=2pt](-[6,0.5]OH)>[1,0.7](-[6,0.5]OH)-[3,0.7]
O-[4]?(-[2,0.3]-[3,0.5]OH)}\arrow 2
\chemfig{ H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-OH} +
2 CO2
\schemestop
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: May be enclose everything in `\vcenter{\hbox{\schemestart .. \schemestop}}`.

Comment: In e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/416678/95544 it is said that chemfig align to the first atom. Moving the left-most HO to the height of the corner (e.g. `[0,0.5,2]`) fixes the problem. However, I am not a chemist so I don't know if this matters for the result:-)

Comment: According to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/330078/121799), the first molecule sets the baseline. This suggests that you should start the first scheme with the inner `HO`, which is of course awkward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**: I looked through the chemfig manual and code, and since the comments in the code are in French the success is very limited. (I am not saying that if they were not in French, I'd have found a perfect solution for all cases. ;-) The upshot is that in your example you may just add a second option `[base]` to `\schemestart`, see the end of section 5 of the chemfig manual. (I'd love to write "for more details" but there aren't any and even `base` is not mentioned. ;-) So this yields

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes} % only for illustration purposes
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\schemestart[][base]
\setcrambond{2pt}{}{}
\chemfig[baseline=(OH2)]{HO-[2,0.5,2]?<[7,0.7](-[2,0.5]@{OH2}OH)-[0,,,,
line width=2pt](-[6,0.5]OH)>[1,0.7](-[6,0.5]OH)-[3,0.7]
O-[4]?(-[2,0.3]-[3,0.5]OH)}\arrow 2
\chemfig[baseline=(H2.base)]{@{H2}H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-OH} +
2 CO2
\schemestop
\end{equation}


\begin{equation}
\schemestart
\setcrambond{2pt}{}{}
\chemfig[baseline=(H1.base)]{@{H1}H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-OH} +
2 CO2
\schemestop
\end{equation}


\begin{equation}
\schemestart[][base]
\setcrambond{2pt}{}{}
\chemfig{@{H3}H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-OH} +
2 CO2
\schemestop
\end{equation}


\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[thin,red] (H2.base -| current page text area.west)
-- (H2.base -| current page text area.east);
\draw[thin,red] (H1.base -| current page text area.west)
-- (H1.base -| current page text area.east);
\draw[thin,red] (H3.base -| current page text area.west)
-- (H3.base -| current page text area.east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I added some comparisons and graphical illustrations. I also keep my old answer because it could very well be that one really needs to use the base of a specific molecule, and [the proposal to draw the molecule in such a way that the it starts with the desired molecule](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/330078/121799) might become complicated. That is, I wouldn't know how to draw the left scheme starting at the OH in the middle.

**OLD ANSWER**: By default, the baseline is set to the base of the first molecule. But you can override this. The first step is to give a molecule a name, in the example below this is accomplished by adding `@{OH2}`, and then you can use this for the baseline.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\schemestart
\setcrambond{2pt}{}{}
\chemfig[baseline=(OH2)]{HO-[2,0.5,2]?<[7,0.7](-[2,0.5]@{OH2}OH)-[0,,,,
line width=2pt](-[6,0.5]OH)>[1,0.7](-[6,0.5]OH)-[3,0.7]
O-[4]?(-[2,0.3]-[3,0.5]OH)}\arrow 2
\chemfig{@{H1}H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-OH} +
2 CO2
\schemestop
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The baseline approach is what I prefere. How about using the OH group of the second compound to define the baseline. Then, CO_2 would be aligned with the equation number. But as I understand, the first molecule is inevitably dictating the baseline. So it might not be possible, is it?

Comment: @AlexG OK, I posted what I was able to do. I think this should give you what you want in your specific example, but most likely there will be situations in which additional tricks will be required.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @Manuel, a simpe `\vcenter{\hbox{ ... }}` works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\vcenter{\hbox{\schemestart
\setcrambond{2pt}{}{}
\chemfig{HO-[2,0.5,2]?<[7,0.7](-[2,0.5]OH)-[0,,,,
line width=2pt](-[6,0.5]OH)>[1,0.7](-[6,0.5]OH)-[3,0.7]
O-[4]?(-[2,0.3]-[3,0.5]OH)} \arrow 2
\chemfig{ H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-OH} +
2 CO2
\schemestop}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]